# Confluence - VIM bridge?

Tags: vim, confluence

There is an emacs plugin to directly edit a confluence page in emacs:

http://code.google.com/p/confluence-el/

Is there something similar for VIM? I was not able to find something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [Vimfluence](https://github.com/orlandov/vimfluence)? It's not a Vim plugin but rather an external tool that downloads the page, lets you edit it, and then uploads it again. But it does the job.

Comment: Looks like the perfect solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

[It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125/) is a Firefox plugin that lets you use any text editor to edit text fields.

Comment: Good idea, but I could already do that with vimperator. I was looking for an external XML-RPC bridge.

Comment: I use It's All Text and I'm highly satisfied with the firefox-vim combination.